# how to add list items to stringbuffer?

Tags: java, string, list, stringbuffer

I've got a list which contains a string that is split up, i want to add the items from the list to a stringbuffer but im currently failing to do so

Here is my code that i currently got:

```
 public void AAAAA(String text, int width)
  {
    List<String> items = Arrays.asList(text.split(" "));
    StringBuffer use = new StringBuffer(items);
    use.insert(width, "\n");
    System.out.println(use);
  }
```

how would i go about adding all my items to the stringbuffer?

Comment: Are you trying to replace the delimiter from space to line feed (`\n`)?

Comment: What do you want to do with the "width" input? Check javadoc for StringBuffer on how to user insert and append methods 
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html

Comment: `new StringBuffer(items)` ? Are you sure this line compiles well?

Comment: @LittleSanti it doesnt.

Comment: @manlike You'd better begin by explain exactly what do you need, what input data do you have and what results do you expect.

Comment: @LittleSanti i want to add the elements from the list to the stringbuffer. `String text` is some random text. `int width` is random interger between 0-20, the challenge is to add a new line at a specific index of the elements in the stringbuffer. Which is why i have `use.insert(width, "\n")` in the example above

Comment: And why do you need to split the input string by blanks?

Comment: @LittleSanti So i could add a new line at which ever index i like.

Comment: Please don't use comments to clarify, [edit] your question instead. Comments may or may not be shown initially. They do appear in order of votes. You also cannot format code properly in comments. Make it easy to help you by putting everything in one place --- the question.

Comment: Could you please update your question as to what you want to do with the `width` attribute with an example.

Comment: Also, use `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: @chrylis can i use split on stringbuilder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert a character (newline in your case) into an arbitrary index of a string, you don't need to split the string. Just pass it to a `StringBuilder` (because `StringBuilder` allows you to **modify** its contents, while `String` does not) and then do the insertion through the `insert` method.

## Update

To insert a character into an arbitrary list of words, instead, you need to split the input text, through `Arrays.asList` as you tried, right; then do the insertion **into the list object** through the `add` method. And, at the end, you can serialize the items back to a string iterating the elements and concatenating them out to a StringBuilder using blanks as separators.

Comment: i tried the insert method but it cuts a word in half instead of using whole words, that is why i was using the split function on the list show in my example, is there anyway i could fix this?